# Windows 8 C# accessing a file from multiple places getting Access denied error

Tags: c#, .net, file, windows-8, locking

I am trying to save some data in a file but this file is getting accessed multiple times from different methods hence giving me access denied error. How can I apply lock on the following method to access file?

Code:

```
public static async Task SaveDataToFileAsync<T>(string key, T value, bool roaming = false, Type[] extraTypes = null)
{
    var file = roaming ? await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync(key + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting) :
    await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync(key + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    var xml = Xml.Serialize<T>(value, extraTypes);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, xml, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
}

public static async Task<T> GetdataFromFileAsync<T>(string key, T defaultValue, bool roaming = false, Type[] extraTypes = null)
{
    var file = roaming ? await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync(key + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists) :
    await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync(key + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    var xml = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(xml) ? Xml.Deserialize<T>(xml, extraTypes) : defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Stephen Toub's `AsyncLock`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx). `AsyncLock` is also available as [part of](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLock) my AsyncEx library.

Here's an example of `AsyncLock`, which has a more natural syntax than `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private static AsyncLock mutex = new AsyncLock();
public static async Task SaveDataToFileAsync<T>(string key, T value, bool roaming = false, Type[] extraTypes = null)
{
  using (await mutex.LockAsync())
  {
    var file = roaming ? await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync(key + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting) :
    await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync(key + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    var xml = Xml.Serialize<T>(value, extraTypes);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, xml, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the thing you need. As an aside, sometimes you can prevent this complexity by changing the flow of your application. Perhaps parallel access is not a necessity. It usually isn't; and if you think about it, it can't be anyway.